# "Do you mind if I use your cellphone" or "Would you mind if I use your cellphone"? Which one is more polite?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would),

"**would**" is *used to ask somebody politely to do something*

Ex: *Would you mind leaving us alone for a few minutes?*

However, I think that explanation is so simple or it does not explain clearly.

"**would**" make your sentence more hesitative since it is giving a hypothesis.

And to make a sentence more polite with "would", we have to look at the real meaning of a sentence.

Ex: "**Do you mind if I use your cellphone?**" (the listener doesn't have to hesitate to mind it, the listener is welcome to mind it, it makes the question less forceful & therefore is more polite) is more polite than "**Would you mind if I use your cellphone?**" (the listener hesitates to mind it, it makes the question more forceful & therefore is less polite)

But "**Would you mind leaving us alone for a few minutes?**" (the listener hesitates to mind it, it makes the question less forceful & therefore is more polite) is more polite than "**Do you mind leaving us alone for a few minutes?**" (the listener doesn't have to hesitate to mind it, the listener is welcome to mind it, it makes the question more forceful & therefore is less polite)

"**Do you mind if I use your cellphone**" or "**Would you mind if I use your cellphone**"? **Which one is more polite?**

Answer (score 1):

"Would" is more polite.  "Do you mind" means the action is already underway and you're asking the person if that bothers them.  "Would you mind" asks about a hypothetical situation that hasn't happened yet.

Note, though, that neither form actually asks to borrow the phone.  Technically, they just take a survey.  It's common for a wise guy to stand there and say, "No, I don't mind", and not offer their phone.  "Could I please borrow your cellphone?" would be more likely to avoid that.